# Can you monitor multiple urlpatterns with Django's runserver autoreload

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

In the project I'm working on, I'd like to have it run 2 apps on one runserver for development purposes (standalone in production), to utilize amongs others autoreload options.

What I'd like to do is have wsgi application, and asgi application by implementing Django channels next to it.
For that, I feel like I need to have 2 ROOT_URLCONFs basically,
as one would apply to wsgi, and other to asgi application.
I am interested is there a way to make runserver pay attention to multiple ROOT_URLCONFs or urlpatterns whatever you want to name them?
And does this approach make sense in the first place,
as from what I've seen on the web, it's not such an uncommon setup,
but I haven't seen anyone placing it under one runserver.

For the ease of development setup it would be one server,
as there's already an overhead on startup of the project development.